# Mobile (iOS) libraries for authenticating a wallet / wallet signin?

Tags: ios

I'd like to build an iOS app that connects to a given wallet, authenticates it, and then pulls any associated NFTs. On web, of course I'd just use the Metamask web3 hooks, but is there a similar tool for building natively on iOS in Swift?

Comment: I have been looking for the same thing but haven't found anything. I ended up using WalletConnect libraries in Webview to connect to the wallet. Hopefully something native will pop up in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up building in React Native, using WalletConnect for the login API and Moralis for the NFT API. Worked pretty well for this usecase, and I documented [my  process on Medium here.](https://nickconfrey.medium.com/how-to-write-mobile-web3-crypto-apps-on-ios-and-android-3c0854e2110f)

Comment: Thanks for posting. Wonder if there's a native way to do it?